# TableViewCell view disappear

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, cell

I have UITextField at my UItableviewCell , when I click done button on keyboard , my Cell views is removed from Superview

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.selectionStyle = .none
    line.backgroundColor = .custom_gray()
    line.snp.makeConstraints { (cons) in
        cons.bottom.left.right.equalTo(phone).inset(0)
        cons.height.equalTo(0.5)
    }
    stack.snp.makeConstraints { (cons) in
        cons.left.right.equalTo(self).inset(25)
        cons.centerY.equalTo(self)
        cons.height.equalTo(230)
        cons.bottom.equalTo(self).inset(15)
    }
    stack.dropShadow()
    stack.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: can you tell us that where you write this method `layoutSubviews` ? in customTableViewCell or anywhere ?

Comment: in customTableViewCell

Comment: what are you doing on "Done" button click event of keyboard ?

Comment: for keyboard I use IQKeyboard Manager , when I add TextField to UITableViewCell , and tap any button of Keyboard , my view is vanishes . When I add keyboard on view of controller everything is OK

Comment: have you doing reload table or anything when keyboard dismiss ?

Comment: I don't call anything on click

Comment: I have the inverse problem. I have a table that's loaded, and the contentView of various cells have views and some of the views have sublayers. When the textfield is tapped, the keyboard shows, and when it does, the view disappears in one of the cells. And I'm not doing anything with the textfield or to explicitly show the keyboard, it merely does it when the textfield becomes the first responder.  Reloading the table view works, but it makes one of the cells look like it's blinking - view disappears, and then re-appears. Would like to not have that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem By adding my View Into `TableviewCell` content view

```
 self.contentView.addSubview(stack)
 phone.delegate = self
 password.delegate = self
 stack.snp.makeConstraints { (cons) in
        cons.left.right.equalTo(self.contentView).inset(25)
        cons.centerY.equalTo(self.contentView)
        cons.height.equalTo(230)
        cons.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).inset(15)
 }
 self.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
```

and I return this view from `tableviewHeaderContent`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let head = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerid) as! ProfileLoginTableViewCell
        return head.contentView
    }
```